# Connected App -Oauth Usage details not getting captured

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

I have a custom Connected App configured in my org.We have an Integration profile with limited access and an Integration user(dummy user created just for connected app) .We have a 3rd Party application outside the SF system which makes Restful calls using this connected app.
**When it comes to User impersonation, We do not see any restriction at the OAuth level where I can restrict Users who can connect via this connected App**.
If I Set OAuth Permitted User to Admin Approved and set Profile restriction then any User other then that Profile Users can't access the system from 3rd party app.

**Also what does the OAuth Usage actually show?** 
I am not seeing any entries under OAuth Usage for the Integration User who is accessing the System via this connected app but I see User level Login history.